# Optimization of If statement in a Loop

Tags: vb.net, loops, optimization, if-statement, directx

I have the following code that runs inside a loop that is executed 100 000 times per frame (it is a game):

```
If (_vertices(vertexIndex).X > _currentPosition.X - 100) And (_vertices(vertexIndex).X < _currentPosition.X + 100) And (_vertices(vertexIndex).X Mod 4) And (_vertices(vertexIndex).Z Mod 4) Then
_grassPatches(i Mod 9).Render(_vertices(vertexIndex))
End If
```

With this code my game runs at around 8 FPS. If I comment out the `Render` line, the game runs at around 100 FPS, however, if I comment out the whole `If` loop, the framerate increases to around 400 FPS. I don't understand why does this `If ... And ... And ... And ... Then` loop slows down my game so much. Is it because of the multiple `And`s?

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**
Here is one of the ways I tried to improve the performance (also includes some extra code to show context):

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim vertex As Vector3
Dim curPosX As Integer

For vertexIndex As Integer = _startIndex To _endIndex
    vertex = _vertices(vertexIndex)
    curPosX = _currentPosition.X

    If (vertex.X > curPosX - 100) And (vertex.X < curPosX + 100) And (vertex.X Mod 4) And (vertex.Z Mod 4) Then
        _grassPatches(i Mod 9).Render(_vertices(vertexIndex))
    End If
    i += 1
Next
```

**EDIT 2:** could my problem be due to a **Branch Prediction** fail? ([Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902))

**EDIT 3:** I also tried replacing all the `And`s with `AndAlso`s. This didn't lead to any performance benefit.

Comment: What happens when you change `And` by `AndAlso`?

Comment: Same thing. The game averages around 8FPS.

Comment: Are the X and Y accessors doing any computations ?, also what kind of container is _vertices ?

Comment: Another idea: put `_vertices(vertexIndex)` and `_currentPosition.X` into variables and use those variables in your If statement.

Comment: @mrlucmorin `_vertices` is an array of type `Vector3`

Comment: @ZippyV Thanks, but it doesn't help much, it gives me an extra 2 FPS. I updated my question with some more code.

Comment: @mrlucmorin I think that the `X` and `Y` accessors are just properties. This is the desctiption: `Retrieves or sets the x component of any 3-D vector.`

Comment: You're not showing that you have used `AndAlso` instead of `And`. Have you really tried replacing all `And` operators by `AndAlso` ?

Comment: @mrlucmorin Yes, sorry, forgot that bit.

Comment: Just a hunch, but the Mod operator is probably very expensive. Any way to avoid it ?

Comment: @mrlucmorin Yes! Thank you, that fixed it! The reason for the `Mod` operator was to render at every 4th vertex. I guess I'm just gonna have to do that another way. If you want the points, post this is an answer and I'll  set it as the `accepted` answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem probably comes from the use of the `Mod` operator. If you can avoid using it, or find another way of getting to your result, it will make your loop faster.

Cheers